# Elixir:value from a list

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

eg:

```elixir
ModuleName.function_name([10,20,20,30], 20)
#⇒ 2
```

I tried it using `Enum` but it’s especially said that built-in functions cant be used. Can someone give me a solution?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s a homework and the user has been created to ask this question only. Flagged.

Answer (score 2):

A simple and idiomatic way would rely on [`Enum.count/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#count/2):

```elixir
iex> Enum.count([10,20,20,30], & &1 == 20)
2
```

If you want to avoid relying on built-in functions, you need to write your own recursive function:

```elixir
  def count_occurrences(list, value), do: do_count_occurrences(list, value, 0)

  defp do_count_occurrences([], _value, acc), do: acc

  defp do_count_occurrences([value | tail], value, acc) do
    do_count_occurrences(tail, value, acc + 1)
  end

  defp do_count_occurrences([_head | tail], value, acc) do
    do_count_occurrences(tail, value, acc)
  end
```

But the reason we have `Enum` is to avoid doing this every time :)

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here is an idiomatic non-recursive solution with [`for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension.

```elixir
{list, value} = {[10, 20, 20, 30], 20}
for ^value <- list, reduce: 0, do: (acc -> acc + 1)
#⇒ 2
```